# Как отключить пункт меню, на котором находится пользователь?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Имеется меню.
Пользователь перешел по ссылке в меню.
Как отключить эту ссылку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="menu">
    <a href="http://test.com/asd">asd</a>
    <a href="http://test.com/def">def</a>
</div>
```

---

```
var x=document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0],i=0;
for(;i<x.length;i++)
   if(window.location.href==x[i].href)
      x[i].className='current-item';
```